# Python class that extends int doesn't entirely behave like an int

Tags: python

I'm seeing some weird behavior when trying to convert a string to a class I wrote that extends `int`. Here's a simple program that demonstrates my problem:

```
class MyInt(int):
    pass

toInt = '123456789123456789123456789'

print "\nConverting to int..."
print type(int(toInt))

print "\nConverting to MyInt..."
print type(MyInt(toInt))
```

Since `MyInt` is empty, I expected that it would behave exactly like an `int`. Instead, here's the output I got from the program above:

```
Converting to int...
<type 'long'>

Converting to MyInt...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "int.py", line 9, in <module>
    print type(MyInt(toInt))
OverflowError: long int too large to convert to int
```

The string can't convert to a `MyInt`! What about the way I wrote `MyInt` causes it to behave differently than its base class? In this case, there seems to be some kind of maximum on `MyInt`; are there other properties that get implicitly imposed like this when a built-in class is extended in Python? And, finally, is there a way to change `MyInt` so that it doesn't have this maximum anymore?

Comment: Have you considered inheriting from long instead of int?

Comment: Use Python 3 or derive from long. Why are you deriving from an int, anyway? Composition will probably be better for whatever you're doing.

Comment: While I agree with these comments from a practical perspective, I am also curious why the sample code is behaving like that.  What is it about int() that is creating a long and why is that not being inherited?

Comment: This behavior isn't blocking any work I'm doing. I'm mainly just curious about why it's happening. It's something we stumbled on while trying different design options.

Comment: int, I believe, is both a function and a type and when you call it as int(some) value the behavior is defined by the \_\_int\_\_ property of the class that is being passed in,  the strings \_\_int\_\_ function likely returns a long if needed. 

the second version with MyInt is calling the int constructor and passing in the first argument which is then trying to convert it explicitly to only an int

Comment: @JoranBeasley This is usually accomplished with `__new__`, which would be inherited.  The puzzling thing about this, is that this feature doesn't seem to be inherited.  In other words, do you know if there's a reason they didn't use `__new__` for this case?

Comment: no int(x) is a \_\_builtin\_\_.int function ... that calls whatever class x's \_\_int\_\_ method, in this case it is calling basestring.\_\_int\_\_ ... at least im fairly sure thats whats  going on

Comment: @JoranBeasley I think I see what you are saying, though it doesn't appear that basestring has an `__int__` property/method (at least I can't find it).  I sure this is all because 'int' is a builtin, but I'm confused as to why it doesn't act like something implemented in pure-python.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The secret is all in the `__new__()` method:

```
>>> class MyInt(int): pass
>>> MyInt.__new__ == int.__new__
True
>>> MyInt.__new__(MyInt, '123456789101234567890')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
>>> MyInt.__new__(int, '123456789101234567890')
123456789101234567890L
```

Basically when you instantiate a class the very first thing that happens (before `__init__(self, *args)`) is that `__new__(cls, *args)` is called. It is passed the class object as its first argument. The `__new__` method for `int` (which is inherited by `MyInt`) only performs the conversion to `long` if the class it is passed is `int`. I assume this is to avoid messing up subclasses, since converted `MyInt` to `long` would remove all the special functionality you added.

You should use `long` as your base class if you want integers bigger than `int` can handle.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully, this session with the interpreter will provide some insight as to what is happening:

```
>>> i = 1
>>> print type(i), i
<type 'int'> 1
>>> i = int((i << 31) - 1)
>>> print type(i), i
<type 'int'> 2147483647
>>> i += 1
>>> print type(i), i
<type 'long'> 2147483648
>>>
```

Your class is not inheriting this behavior because Python probably treats `int` objects as a special case.

Comment: The OP's example shows that the extended class is *not* inheriting this behavior, I think that's what is most peculiar about it.